# Touchscreen on embedded Linux can't tap / click

Tags: linux, x11, touch-screen, yocto

I use a 7" display with resistive touchscreen, embedded Linux for ARM CPU. Manufacturer Engicam, design is similar to Freescale / NXP i.MX6 Sabre board.

With Yocto 1.7.3 and Engicam board support package I created an X11 application, basically a Firefox browser. Most of this application work with one exception: I can't tap / click on any item. When I touch the screen and move around, cursor will follow my finger, unfortunately a click or double click will not work.

My configuration:

Kernel: `Linux display 3.10.17-1.0.2_ga+g33597e3 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun May 22 20:00:34 CEST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Resistive touch driver: `max11801_ts`, and event driver `evdev`.

The configuration file for evdev (`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf`):

```
#
# Catch-all evdev loader for udev-based systems
# We don't simply match on any device since that also adds accelerometers
# and other devices that we don't really want to use. The list below
# matches everything but joysticks.

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev tablet catchall"
        MatchIsTablet "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
        Option "SHMConfig" "true"
        Option "TapButton1" "1"
        Option "EmulateThirdButton" "1"
        Option "EmulateThirdButtonTimeout" "750"
        Option "EmulateThirdButtonMoveThreshold" "30"
        Option "Calibration" "0 4095 0 4095"
EndSection
```

The last section is used by evdev for touchscreen.

In X11 log I see that X11 loads evdev and accepts the settings:
Part of X11 log (`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`):

```
[3738325.274] (**) max11801_ts: Applying InputClass "evdev touchscreen catchall"
[3738325.274] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[3738325.275] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[3738325.289] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[3738325.289]   compiled for 1.14.4, module version = 2.9.0
[3738325.289]   Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[3738325.289]   ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 19.1
[3738325.289] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'max11801_ts'
[3738325.290] (**) max11801_ts: always reports core events
[3738325.293] (**) evdev: max11801_ts: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[3738325.294] (--) evdev: max11801_ts: Vendor 0 Product 0
[3738325.295] (--) evdev: max11801_ts: Found absolute axes
[3738325.295] (--) evdev: max11801_ts: Found x and y absolute axes
[3738325.295] (--) evdev: max11801_ts: Found absolute touchscreen
[3738325.295] (II) evdev: max11801_ts: Configuring as touchscreen
[3738325.296] (**) Option "EmulateThirdButton" "1"
[3738325.296] (**) Option "EmulateThirdButtonTimeout" "750"
[3738325.296] (**) Option "EmulateThirdButtonMoveThreshold" "30"
[3738325.297] (**) evdev: max11801_ts: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[3738325.297] (**) evdev: max11801_ts: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[3738325.297] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/soc0/soc.1/2100000.aips-bus/21a0000.i2c/i2c-0/0- 0048/input/input0/event0"
[3738325.297] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "max11801_ts" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 6)
[3738325.299] (II) evdev: max11801_ts: initialized for absolute axes.
[3738325.300] (**) max11801_ts: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[3738325.301] (**) max11801_ts: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[3738325.301] (**) max11801_ts: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[3738325.301] (**) max11801_ts: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[3738325.305] (II) config/udev: Adding input device max11801_ts (/dev/input/mouse0)
[3738325.305] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[3738325.305] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Also xinput sees the touch device:

```
# xinput list
| Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
|   > Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
|   > max11801_ts                               id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
| Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
| Virtual core XTEST keyboard                   id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Unfortunately evtest do not see any click (EV_KEY) (BTN_TOUCH) events:

```
# evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:      max11801_ts
Select the device event number [0-0]: 0
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x18 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "max11801_ts"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value   1308
      Min        0
      Max     4095
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value    476
      Min        0
      Max     4095
    Event code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max        1
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1464027536.266584, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1167
Event: time 1464027536.266584, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 2282
Event: time 1464027536.266584, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 1
Event: time 1464027536.266584, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1464027536.282916, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1168
Event: time 1464027536.282916, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1464027536.299472, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1169
Event: time 1464027536.299472, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1464027536.315900, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1171
Event: time 1464027536.315900, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 2281
Event: time 1464027536.315900, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1464027536.340587, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1172
Event: time 1464027536.340587, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1464027536.348821, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1173
Event: time 1464027536.348821, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1464027536.357047, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1174
Event: time 1464027536.357047, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 2283
Event: time 1464027536.357047, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1464027536.365190, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE), value 0
Event: time 1464027536.365190, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
```

evtest do *not* see any EV_KEY /BTN_TOUCH events.

I did some more research and find, ts_test will see BTN_TOUCH events:

```
# TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/touchscreen0 ts_test
1464048778.716232:    399    239      1
1464048778.724452:    399    239      1
1464048778.732621:    399    239      1
1464048778.740965:    399    238      1
1464048778.749177:    399    237      1
1464048778.757422:    399    236      0
```

I assume last column are the BTN_TOUCH events.

I also tried xinput_calibrator

```
# xinput_calibrator
Calibrating EVDEV driver for "max11801_ts" id=6
        current calibration values (from XInput): min_x=0, max_x=4095 and  min_y=0, max_y=4095
```

The upper left cross hair will show up, when I touch the cross hair with a pen, cursor moves to this position but `xinput_calibrator` do not get an click event.

The same issue with Firefox, I can't tap / click any items.

Why doensn't evtest see the BTN_TOUCH events? Is this an configuration issue or a bug?
How can I get click events?

Comment: Great :-/ I have the same problem with a LUMIO CrystalTouch ver 02.04.77.01